# What level of French education is generally considered to be equivalent to a U.S. Bachelor's degree: 3rd year of Licence or 1st year of Master?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, university, united-states, france

In France there are three levels (these are the same for most countries in Europe I think):

- Licence (3 years)
- Master (2 years)
- Doctorat (about 3 years)

In the U.S. I believe there are three levels:

- Undergraduate (4 years) after which we earn a "Bachelor's degree"
- Graduate (about 2-3 years I think) after which we earn a "Master's degree" maybe (I'm not sure at all)
- Doctorate (or maybe this is included in the "Graduate" part? I don't know)

I'm a French student and I'm planning to arrive in the U.S. for the beginning of the Graduate part (I'm going to study astronomy).

I know I should begin the application process at least 7-8 months before leaving France, but should I be leaving right after I finish the 3rd year of Licence or right after I finish the 1st year of Master?

In other words... Which one is generally considered to be equivalent to a U.S. Bachelor's degree: the 3rd year of Licence or the 1st year of Master?

Does it depends on the quality of the universities?
Maybe second-rate universities accept students who have the 3rd year of Licence to their Graduate programs ; while first-rate universities only accept students who have the 1st year of Master to their Graduate programs?

Comment: Whether or not you're accepted depends on many factors, but the License corresponds to a B.S. Obviously, having additional positive factors (all or part of a masters; having your degree from an Ecole; ..) will help.